# Filter text from /var/log/messages and forward in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using logstash and was not able to figure out how to filter. I want to filter the following log from /var/log/messages and forward only the line which contain [INFO] in it.

```
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for illegal user user from 219.117.251.250 port 44741 ssh2
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44817 ssh2
mingus  sshd[2264]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44866 ssh2
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44918 ssh2
mingus  sshd[2268]: Illegal user test from 219.117.251.250
mingus  sshd[2268]: Failed password for illegal user test from 219.117.251.250 port 44997 ssh2
```

I was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible! Use the [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) filter to extract the information you need. You can use this to get a field containing the inside of "sshd[(some string here)]". Example:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "mingus  sshd\[%{WORD:messagetype}\]: %{GREEDYDATA}"]
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you can use a conditional over the output such that only lines containing INFO will be passed. Example:

```
output {
    if [messagetype] == "INFO" {
        stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helped!

EDIT:
Here is my conf file:

```
input {
    stdin {}
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "mingus  sshd\[%{WORD:messagetype}\]: %{GREEDYDATA}"]
    }
}
output {
    if [messagetype] == "INFO" {
        stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
        }
    }
}
```

The choice to use stdin and stdout was simple to make debugging easy. Using the snippet of log lines provided, I put in this input:

```
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for illegal user user from 219.117.251.250 port 44741   ssh2
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44817 ssh2
mingus  sshd[2264]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44866 ssh2
mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44918 ssh2
mingus  sshd[2268]: Illegal user test from 219.117.251.250
mingus  sshd[2268]: Failed password for illegal user test from 219.117.251.250 port 44997 ssh2
```

and received the following output:

```
{
        "message" => "mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for illegal user user from         219.117.251.250 port 44741 ssh2",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2014-07-31T13:59:34.376Z",
           "host" => "cmssrv221.fnal.gov",
    "messagetype" => "INFO"
}
{
        "message" => "mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44817 ssh2",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2014-07-31T13:59:34.378Z",
           "host" => "cmssrv221.fnal.gov",
    "messagetype" => "INFO"
}
{
        "message" => "mingus  sshd[INFO]: Failed password for root from 219.117.251.250 port 44918 ssh2",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2014-07-31T13:59:34.387Z",
           "host" => "cmssrv221.fnal.gov",
    "messagetype" => "INFO"
}
```

This, based on the information you gave me, appears to be what you want. If this not what you wanted, you'll have to be more specific.

By the way, I am using logstash 1.4.1, just in case you are using a vastly different version.

Comment: I tried it and that is not working as per my need. I am still getting all logs including ERROR and WARNING. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm it works for me, at least it appears to work though perhaps you are looking for something even more specific... one moment.

Comment: I think I have done something wrong, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058191/filtering-specific-lines-from-log-file-in-logstash?noredirect=1#comment39144214_25058191 link I have my logstash configuration there exactly same